# Need help understanding Linux script for failed Zbar configuration output

Tags: linux, imagemagick, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have imageMick installed in my WSL Linux/Debian environment. I have verified with the command `magick -version`. Im attempting to run the command `./configure --disable-video` to configure zbar and eventually build the zbarimg program.

i get this error message

```
checking for MAGICK... checking for MAGICK... configure: error: in `/etc/zbar-0.10':
configure: error: Unable to find ImageMagick >= 6.2.6:
```

it fails at this part in the script

```
pkg_failed=no
{ $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: checking for MAGICK" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for MAGICK... " >&6; }

if test -n "$MAGICK_CFLAGS"; then
    pkg_cv_MAGICK_CFLAGS="$MAGICK_CFLAGS"
 elif test -n "$PKG_CONFIG"; then
    if test -n "$PKG_CONFIG" && \
    { ($as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors \"MagickWand >= 6.2.6\"") >&5
  ($PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "MagickWand >= 6.2.6") 2>&5
  ac_status=$?
  $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  (exit $ac_status); }; then
  pkg_cv_MAGICK_CFLAGS=`$PKG_CONFIG --cflags "MagickWand >= 6.2.6" 2>/dev/null`
else
  pkg_failed=yes
```

The entire file is found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/main/configure

Im not too well versed on Linux scripting, so Im not sure what command this scirpt is attempting to run, where the end result is that it cannot find ImageMick, yet I do have ImageMick installed. Im also unsure of what value to to set the environment variables as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" it with `sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config`. Turns out there seems to be an issue with magickwand.h not being installed. But at least its a different error